# Array Filter not working (With working snippet)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter the `array` by the `numbers`. Basically, car with id `48` should be deleted because it does not exist on `numbers`

What am I missing here??

```js
const numbers = [49, 482, 49, 49, 49, 1135, 49, 1709, 1044, 1016, 30];


const array = [{
  cars: [{
    id: 48
  }, {
    id: 49
  }]
}];


array.forEach(elem => elem.cars.filter(car => !numbers.includes(car.id)));

console.log(array);
```

I want to keep the same structure, I just want tot delete the car with id `48`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested `forEach`

```js
const numbers = [49, 482, 49, 49, 49, 1135, 49, 1709, 1044, 1016, 30];


const array = [{
  cars: [{
    id: 48
  }, {
    id: 49
  }]
}];


array.forEach(elm => {
  const cars = [];
  elm.cars.forEach(car => {
    if(numbers.includes(car.id)) {
      cars.push({id: car.id});
    }  
  });
  elm.cars = cars;
});

console.log(array);
```

Or a `reduce` within `forEach`

```js
const numbers = [49, 482, 49, 49, 49, 1135, 49, 1709, 1044, 1016, 30];


const array = [{
  cars: [{
    id: 48
  }, {
    id: 49
  }]
}];


array.forEach(elm => {
  elm.cars = elm.cars.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (numbers.includes(curr.id)) {
      acc.push({
        id: curr.id
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I want to keep the same structure but just delete the car object with id `48`

Comment: updated answer with the structure maintained

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to acheive the expected result.

The idea is to change the filter condition which allows to keep the car objects id found in the `numbers` array and eliminate rest.

In your approach [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is just iteration without returning anything and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not mutate the actual array.

```js
const numbers = [49, 482, 49, 49, 49, 1135, 49, 1709, 1044, 1016, 30];

const array = [
  {
    cars: [
      {
        id: 48,
      },
      {
        id: 49,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const res = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev.push({ cars: curr.cars.filter((car) => numbers.includes(car.id)) });
  return prev;
}, []);

console.info("result::", res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const numbers = [49, 482, 49, 49, 49, 1135, 49, 1709, 1044, 1016, 30];

const array = [
    {
        cars: [{id: 48,},{id: 49,}],
    },
];

array.forEach((elem) => {
    const elemCopy = elem;
    elemCopy.cars = elem.cars.filter((car) => numbers.includes(car.id))
});

console.log(array);
```

Please refer the code, while iterating over array we can mutate the cars array.